# What is a correct way to prove that a sequence driven by white noise is a Markov sequence? [Discrete-time Wiener Process]

Tags: stochastic-processes, conditional-probability, independence, markov-process, random-walk

**Claim**: a sequence $x(k)$ driven by simple state evolution with white "Gaussian" noise $n(k)$ below is a Markov sequence

\begin{align}
x(0) &= 0 \\
x(k+1) &= x(k) + n(k), \quad k = 0, 1, 2, \dots,
\end{align}
where the white noise $n(k)$ has zero mean for all $k$, and covariance $\mathbb{E}[n(k)n^{\top}(j)] = C\delta_{kj},$ with Kronecker delta $\delta_{jk}$, and a constant $C$, where $C>0$, making the variance time-invariant resulting in a stationary white "Gaussian" noise. Additionally, $x(0)$ is also Gaussian.

How can I show that this is Markov?

The definition of Markov property I use is given below:

$$p[x(t)|x(\tau), \tau \leq t_1] = p[x(t)|x(t_1)] \quad \forall t>t_1$$

and I want to show: $p[x(k))|x(k-1), x(k-2), \dots, x(0)] = p[x(k)|x(k-1)]$.

**Attempt:**

\begin{align}
p[x(k))|x(k-1), \dots, x(0)] &= p[x(k)|x(k-1), n(k-3), n(k-4), \dots, n(0)] \quad\text{$\dots(1)$}\\
&= \frac{p[x(k),x(k-1), n(k-3), n(k-4), \dots, n(0)]}{p[x(k-1), n(k-3), n(k-4), \dots, n(0)]}\quad\text{$\dots(2)$}\\
\end{align}
For $(1)$, I make repetitive substitutions $x(k-2) = x(k-3) + n(k-3), x(k-3) = x(k-4) + n(k-4), \dots, x(k-k) = x(0) = 0.$

From $(2)$, I want to write:

$$p[x(k), x(k-1), n(k-3), \dots, n(0)] = p[x(k), x(k-1)]\cdot p[n(k-3)] \cdot \cdot \cdot p[n(0)]$$ on the numerator and $$p[x(k-1), n(k-3), n(k-4) , \dots, n(0)] = p[x(k-1)]\cdot p[n(k-3)] \cdot p[n(k-4)] \cdot \cdot \cdot p[n(0)]$$ on the denominator and cancel out, resulting in
$$
p[x(k))|x(k-1), x(k-2), \dots, x(0)] = \frac{p[x(k), x(k-1)]}{p[x(k-1)]}\quad\text{$\dots(3)$}\\
$$

I am not sure if I am using a valid argument from $(2)$ to $(3)$ since the only fact I know about the white noise $n(k)$ is that its autocovariance is zero for two different times.

But does this fact also imply the independence of $n(k)$ and $n(j)$ for $k \neq j$ (which is what I am using)?

---

**Edit after comments help**

Generally, the noise in this process (discrete-time Wiener process) is drawn from iid Gaussian.

But I am not using Gausiann property anywhere and this raises a concern in my attempt. Is it necessary or can I drop the Gaussian assumption and still claim Markovness?

Otherwise, how should I use the "Gaussian" part in the proof for this process being Markov?

Comment: If you only know the noises are uncorrelated then you cannot conclude that $x$ is Markov. For example one way the noises could be uncorrelated would be if $n(k+1)=s_k n(k)$ where $s_k$ are iid and are $\pm 1$ with equal probabilities, and $n(0)$ is sampled from some nondegenerate distribution.

Comment: @Ian, what do I need then? I am just given that the white noise sequence $n(k)$ is zero mean for all $k$ and the covariance $Cov[n(k), n(j)] = C\delta_{kj}$, where the dirac delta is $\delta_{kj} = 1$ for $k = j$ and $0$ for else.

Comment: Are the noises also jointly Gaussian? Just knowing they are uncorrelated, or even that they are separately Gaussian and uncorrelated, is *not* sufficient.

Comment: @Ian No, the only assumption on the noise is that it is white with zero mean.

Comment: Then you're stuck, the process is not generally Markov.

Comment: @Ian this seems to be a standard result in a random dynamical system though (called discrete-time Wiener process). I am given that $x(0)$ is Gaussian but no Gaussian assumption is given about the noise. Does that make any differences?

Comment: In the discrete time Wiener process the noises are indeed jointly Gaussian. Probably the standard way you'd see this written is when describing a discretization of the ordinary Wiener process, for which you have an underlying timestep $h$ and then $x(0)=0$ and the increments $n(k)$ are given by iid $N(0,h)$ variables. You can certainly set $h=1$ in this if you are not interested in the continuum limit.

Comment: @Ian,  Sorry, my textbook (Bar-Shalom et. al., Estimation with Applications to Tracking and Navigation) has no mention of the noise being jointly Gaussian. I will edit the question accordingly.
So, is it a general assumption that $n(k)$ and $n(j)$ are independent because they are drawn from the iid process?

Comment: That's right. ${}{}$

Comment: @Ian
Thank you so much. Would you be able to answer my edited question? I am not sure how the noise being jointly Gaussian plays a part in this proof. I am only relying on independence in my attempt and so I doubt I did it correctly.